# Have list of URLs and the page of each URL has a specific link; any way to extract those links?

Tags: html, unix, sed, awk, grep

The URLs I have are all Reddit links, e.g.

http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/22im98/this_blew_my_mind_a_real_restored_picture_of/

and each of those links have a picture/link at the top of the page (usually to imgur). So here's the picture/link for the above Reddit link

[image: http://imgur.com/dymrL5F]

So is there a way to use wget/curl/awk/sed/grep/cut/etc. to give the reddit link and get the imgur link?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using the [multi-platform web-scraping CLI `xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) with an XPath expression to extract the URL of the link with class `thumbnail`:

```
url='http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/22im98/this_blew_my_mind_a_real_restored_picture_of/'

xidel -q -e '//a[contains(@class, "thumbnail")]/@href' "$url"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
wget -qO - http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/22im98/this_blew_my_mind_a_real_restored_picture_of/ | awk -v RS="http://imgur.com" 'NR==2 {sub(/"$/,"",$1);print RT$1}'
http://imgur.com/dymrL5F
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `wget -q -O -` (as of `GNU wget 1.4`)? Deft use of `awk`, but uses `GNU awk` extensions (if you replace `RT` with `RS`, it'll work with `mawk`, too; no luck with `FreeBSD awk` (OSX; no multi-char. `RS` values supported)).